# Trigger an event on click within body area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger the click, on click on my webpage. I tried the below and it  triggers the click onload and not on click.

```
$(function() { 
            $("body").click(function(e) {

                    alert("code");

            })
            $('#container').trigger('click');
        });
```

Basically I need to show a popup on click of P keyword from keyboard. While I started I got stuck during the initial stages. Not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: what does `on click of P keyword from keyboard` mean? Providing some sample html and a demo would also help

Comment: what does a click have to do with a keypress? Sounds like: you put the mouse on the keyboard and you do a click on the `P` ??

Comment: @roXon    isn't that the way you are supposed to type??

Comment: @charlietfl sometimes it's so nice to be part of this community :) Now I have to make another coffee, (and you owe me that one) cause I spit the last one :D

Comment: @roXon Warning! Coffee is dangerous for your `P` key.

Comment: @VisioN better for a P key than for a G spot

Comment: @roXon I must have prevented propagation to my imagination before reading it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need a [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event where <kbd>P</kbd> key passes ASCII code `80`:

```
$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 80) {
        alert("'p' was pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: If I use jQuery version lower than where than on is defined, will it work. I used bind, but it didn't.

Comment: I need it on click and not keyboard events.

Comment: @Mike `click` event usually fires on mouse button click. It doesn't relate to `P` key on the keyboard.

Comment: but the code for p is 112 and why did you just use 80 which is the keycode for capital P?

Comment: @Mike You mix keyboard key and ASCII code for `P`. Different keyboards might have different keyboard keys for `P`, while ASCII code for `P` is always the same.

Comment: hey thanks for this. can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545416/unable-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-with-jsonp